# get an accurate coordinate from didExitRegion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, cllocationmanager

i'm implementing an app where i need to track user's location by the following:

- track user's location while the app is in the background or closed
- if the user's location is changed for about 2000 meters i should perform an API call.

my approach for this problem is the following:

- the first time the user launches the app i start monitoring for a region using his current location
- if the **didExitRegion** is triggered, i perform the API call and replace the current monitored region by a new region using the current location as the center of the new region.

this works fine when the app is in the foreground as the location that is returned from the location manager is accurate.

But if the app is in the background then the location manager will not return an accurate location since it's running for the first time and the first coordinates that are returned are not accurate.

the question is how can i get an accurate location of the user when the **didExitRegion** is triggered in the background?

thanks

Comment: What about requesting the location manager to update the current coordinates and to use those?

Comment: this is what i'm doing right now, but it does not give an accurate location. i'm wondering if there is a way to get the most accurate location from the location manager.

Comment: Possibly the system changes desiredAccuracy when apps go background?

Comment: @Kassem, were you able to solve this problem? When `didExitRegion` is called, I `startLocationupdate` and wait for a location update delegate call to get the current location.  This works about half the time.  I also do `registerBackgroundTask`, but that doesn't solve the problem.  It always works on simulator, but not reliably on the actual device.

Answer (score 3):

I have not had a lot of luck with `didExitRegion:` firing reliably; it often fires much further away than the edge of my region.

I'd suggest you use `CLLocationManager`'s [`-startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges), if you just need an API call every 2km or so. If your accuracy/precision is important, just register location services as a necessary background state ([`UIBackgroundModes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) in your app plist; you may need to do this to use the significant change API from the background, too), and use the normal `-startUpdatingLocation`, with appropriate [`distanceFilter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter) and [`desiredAccuracy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy) field values on your `CLLocationManager` instance.

Comment: -startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges is not accurate and sometime it fires every 8 KM. currently i'm using the other way you mentioned but it drains the battery so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Several things happening here.

You mentioned that the region change trigger is a little variable.  This is deliberate; to avoid high numbers of triggers being fired as you walk down the boundary between two regions, there is some stickiness to the triggering, in both time and position.

From the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1)

```
The system does not report boundary crossings until the boundary plus a designated cushion distance is exceeded. You specify the desired cushion distance for a region when you register it using the startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: method. This cushion value prevents the system from generating numerous entered and exited events in quick succession while the user is traveling close the edge of the boundary.
```

Getting an accurate position is no different from normal.  You start up the location manager and wait until you get a location update with the desired accuracy.  Shut down the manager and use the position.

Because you're running in the background, you only have ten minutes to do this, and you have to tell the OS that you're doing background processing using UIApplication's startBackgroundTaskWithExceptionHandler.  Plenty of documentation on that elsewhere.

Hope that helps.